# What's the "for" for in a label tag?

Tags: html, forms, usability

Just ran across a `for` parameter in an HTML label tag:

```
<label for="required-firstname"> First Name </label>
<small>*</small>
<input name="required-firstname" type="text" tabindex="2" 
       id="required-firstname" size="24" maxlength="40">
```

I'm converting this form to a PHP processed script, can I get rid of the for= parameters?
(And out of curiosity, what does it do?)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

From w3schools.org:

> The  tag defines a label for an input element.
>
> The label element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the label element, it toggles the control.
>
> The for attribute of the  tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.

HTH!

adding my $.02 as an Accessibility SME - as well as usability, the LABEL also associates the input field with the correct label so persons using screen readers will know what the field is for.

Comment: +1   
`if the user clicks on the text within the label element, it toggles the control.`

Answer (score 23):

The HTML label tag defines a label for a form element.  They're usually used with checkboxes and radio buttons, and when the user clicks on the label it toggles the button.  With a text input (and you'll have to check this to be sure) I think it only gives focus to the input when the user clicks the label.

Comment: This is a HUGE part of making custom checkboxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 9):

It specifies to which element that label is bound to. In your sample code the label is there **for** the *required-firstname* input field. If the user clicks on that label, the focus will go to the bound input field. It's a usability improvement and I think you'd be better off leaving it as is. It's a good practice.

Answer (score 8):

It ties the label to a form element id. Some form elements, like checkboxes, can be activated by clicking on their label.

Answer (score 8):

The "for" attribute is a necessary element for the accessibility of your form. Do not omit it. For someone using a screen reader (SR) to have a web page announced to them, the "for" attribute relates the control to the label. Typically a SR user will tab through a form, from one control (which is a focusable element for the SR) to the next. Without the "for" attribute, the SR user will have to change modes on the SR and probe around the form to try and determine which control matches which label, which can be time-consuming and confusing. The "for" attribute can also be useful for assistive technology relating to motor issues.

WebAIM.org has a great page explaining the accessibility ramifications of "for": http://webaim.org/techniques/forms/controls

Answer (score 3):

In some browsers when you click on a text in a for tag, you'll check the box it's associated with (i.e. the for = id) or put the focus on that box.  It's an ADA thing