# Customize checkbox for images

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, customization

Im triying to make this box 1:1 with css, but I have so low css skills. Picture of the box -> http://prntscr.com/l6kyob (left - when checkbox clicked, right - when its not), live demo here -> https://victorthemes.com/themes/glazov/gallery/photography-trend/

That's what I've done so far

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".image-checkbox").each(function () {
  if ($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().attr("checked")) {
    $(this).addClass('image-checkbox-checked');
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass('image-checkbox-checked');
  }
});


$(".image-checkbox").on("click", function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('image-checkbox-checked');
  var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  $checkbox.prop("checked",!$checkbox.prop("checked"))

  e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```css
      .nopad {
 padding-left: 0 !important;
 padding-right: 0 !important;
}
/*image gallery*/
.image-checkbox {
 cursor: pointer;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 outline: 0;
}
.image-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
 display: none;
}

.image-checkbox-checked {
 border-color: #4783B0;
}
.image-checkbox .fa {
  position: absolute;
  color: #4A79A3;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.image-checkbox-checked .fa {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
  
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nopad text-center">
    <label class="image-checkbox">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="usergalleryimages[]" value="">
      <i class="fa fa-check hidden"></i>
    </label> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nopad text-center">
    <label class="image-checkbox">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="usergalleryimages[]" value="">
      <i class="fa fa-check hidden"></i>
    </label> 
  </div>
```

Please, give me some hints how I can do this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: None of your examples are 1x1. Can you explain better what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

## `<input id='`chk0`' type='checkbox'>` `<label for="`chk0`"></label>`

For CSS, input/label pairs do the following:

#### Tags

- Place the checkbox before the label
- Place anything that changes "state" (ex. off/on) after or within the label

#### Attributes

- Assign `#id` to checkbox and a `.class` that is shared by all checkboxes
- Assign **[`for`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/698017/2813224)** to label with the value of checkbox `#id`

#### CSS

- Use the [**adjacent sibling combinator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and the pseudo-class **[`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)** like so:

  ```
  .classOfCheckbox:checked + label .fa-check {
    display: block;
  }

  .classOfCheckbox:checked + label .fa-times {
    display: none;
  }
  ```

---

### Demo

```css
.nopad {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}


/*image gallery*/

.image-checkbox {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.chk {
  display: none;
}

.chk:checked+.image-checkbox {
  border-color: #4783B0;
}

.image-checkbox .fas {
  position: absolute;
  color: #4A79A3;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.fa-check {
  display: none;
}

.chk:checked+.image-checkbox .fa-check {
  display: block !important;
}

.chk:checked+.image-checkbox .fa-times {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nopad text-center">
  <input id="chk0" class="chk" type="checkbox" name="usergalleryimages[]" value="">
  <label class="image-checkbox" for="chk0">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://victorthemes.com/themes/glazov/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Proofing-three.jpg" />
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i> 
    </label>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nopad text-center">
  <input id="chk1" class="chk" type="checkbox" name="usergalleryimages[]" value="">
  <label class="image-checkbox" for="chk1">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://victorthemes.com/themes/glazov/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/G-Proofing-six.jpg" />
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i> 
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats nice, thank you a lot! But how to move the "x" and "v" symbols to div box attached to the image bottom, like the demo?

Comment: The answer is there you must modify accordingly with the CSS. This site is for users that have done the research and cannot go any further. Your problem is that you wanted a CSS solution to the code you provided. If you want styling help, then at least put in the effort to post the correct code. It's up to you to put forth the effort to post the real code or a good facsimile of said code. Please review how to post a [mcve]. As  Serg Chernata said earlier your code is not 1:1,